# Oracle UCM Custom Reject email from workflow step

Tags: workflow, oracle-ucm, webcenter

I have a single step criteria workflow,after the content is rejected from this step I want to send email to the doc author notifying that the content item has been rejected.

I tried adding following lines of code in the exit event of the workflow step but that does not seem to work and still it is loading the OOTB reject mail template as evident in the logs.

```
<$if wfAction like "APPROVE"$>
<$wfUpdateMetaData("xTested",0)$>
<$endif$>
<$if wfAction like "REJECT"$>
<$wfSet("wfJumpName", "RejectJump")$>
<$wfSet("wfJumpTargetStep", wfCurrentStep(-1))$>
<$wfSet("wfJumpEntryNotifyOff", "1")$>
<$wfNotify(dDocAuthor,"user","MY_REJECT_MAIL")$>
<$endif$>
```

I have also have the custom component with my custom templates enabled in my Component manager.
but in the logs i see the following:

> resourceloader/7 07.31 06:06:37.036 IdcServer-15486 not loading page REDIRECT_TEMPLATE because it is up to date with timestamp 1324323808000
>   resourceloader/7 07.31 06:06:37.036 IdcServer-15486 Checked resources files and 0 out of 110 have changed and it required 0 milliseconds to do the check
>   mail/6 07.31 06:06:37.038 send email queue background mail thread starting
>   mail/6 07.31 06:06:37.038 send email queue Background mail thread active -- 1 packages remain
>   resourceloader/7 07.31 06:06:37.038 send email queue not loading page WF_REJECT_MAIL because it is up to date with timestamp 1355857834000
>   resourceloader/7 07.31 06:06:37.038 send email queue Skipping resource file check because it is too soon since the last one

Can any one tell me where exactly am i going wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Rejections do not trigger the exit event.

> An exit event script is evaluated when a revision has completed the
>   step's approval requirements and the step's extra exit conditions are
>   met.
>   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/doc.1111/e10978/c05_workflows.htm#CSMRC645

The answer is to put your email code in the entry event of the step that the workflow rejects back to.

Here is a good article about workflow rejection in WebCenter Content (UCM): https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/dealing_with_rejection_made_ea

Comment: I tried putting the script in the Entry event of the workflow step ,but still same observation in the logs :(resourceloader/7 08.01 12:57:17.353 IdcServer-35197 not loading page REDIRECT_TEMPLATE because it is up to date with timestamp 1324323808000

>mail/6 08.01 12:57:17.355 send email queue background mail thread starting
>mail/6 08.01 12:57:17.355 send email queue Background mail thread active -- 1 packages remain
>resourceloader/7 08.01 12:57:17.356 send email queue not loading page WF_REJECT_MAIL because it is up to date with timestamp 1355857834000

Comment: It needs to go in the entry event of a different workflow step; it should go in the workflow step that is triggered after the rejection.

Comment: I tried creating another workflow with 2 steps:1st step to notify the docAuthor in case of rejection else move to next step.In the next step ,I am handling the approval part and if the content item is rejected ,i'm moving it back to the notify step.All the script in both steps is in Entry event ,but still the same issue :( email template is not getting called.

Comment: If you turn on full verbose workflow tracing, what does this output?

Comment: This is the output in the logs:>mail/6 08.02 06:46:54.439 send email queue background mail thread starting
>mail/6 08.02 06:46:54.439 send email queue Background mail thread active -- 1 packages remain>resourceloader/7 08.02 06:46:54.439 send email queue not loading page WF_REJECT_MAIL because it is up to date with timestamp 1355857834000

Comment: Any help is highly appreciated!!! I tired following the post -https://forums.oracle.com/message/4183495#4183495 but it also did not fix the issue.